# MQXAConnectionFactory fails to connect with XA Connection

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to connect to MQ using IBM MQXAConnectionFactory.
The following is the code

```
public class Custom {
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws Exception {
        MQXAConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQXAConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHostName(hostName);
        connectionFactory.setPort(port);
        connectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
        connectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
        connectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        connectionFactory.setClientReconnectTimeout(1000);  
        connectionFactory.setMsgBatchSize(10);
        connectionFactory.setUseConnectionPooling(true);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() throws Exception{
        CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        factory.setSessionCacheSize(50);
        factory.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setReconnectOnException(true);
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Custom b = new Custom();
        MQXAConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = (MQXAConnectionFactory) b.cachingConnectionFactory().getTargetConnectionFactory();
        XAConnection xaConnection = cachingConnectionFactory.createXAConnection();
        xaConnection.start();
        XASession session = xaConnection.createXASession();
        MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(session.createQueue(queueName));
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) session.createTextMessage();
        textMessage.setText("pavan");
        session.run();
        messageProducer.send(textMessage);
        xaConnection.stop();
        session.close();
        xaConnection.close();
        System.out.println(xaConnection);   
    }
}
```

This gives an error

```
WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2072' ('MQRC_SYNCPOINT_NOT_AVAILABLE')
```

This works fine with non-xa connection.What am doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of IBM MQ jar files are you using?

Comment: I am using p800-005-160516.2